# dates, columns, conditional formatting, neighbouring cells (below/above)

Tags: vba, excel, date

Hello everybody out there,

I do believe that VBA code is needed for my problem.
So please, be kind and help me.

I have table with many dates (all dates are in one specific column). 
Cells with dates are filled without some special order. 
Filtering is not applicable, because of other data (data in other columns).

What is needed (Problem):

- Is there a way to compare dates of neighbouring cells (cell above/below),
- If dates are same, then copy conditional formatting from 1 cell in column with same date,
- Conditional formatting changes only in case of a different neghbouring dates,

For example:

```
Column (date)   I conditional formatting interior cell color

A           I   (CF)

25.11.2017  I   blue

26.11.2017  I   red

26.11.2017  I   red

26.11.2017  I   red

22.11.2017  I   blue

22.11.2017  I   blue

25.11.2017  I   red

etc.        I   etc.
```

I am familiar with VBA, so VBA code would be great. I do believe, Private Sub is needed here.

Many thanks in advance.

Greetings from Croatia

Marko

Comment: are there spaces between in the actual source column?

Comment: there is not any spaces in cells. it is possible to have empty cell in column

Comment: Please elaborate on the criteria for coloring.

Comment: Coloring criteria - that is main part why I need Your help:
- Cell with changed date (compared to cell above) need to be colored in specific color (for example: red color)
for example – 
cell A2 (26.11.2017) compared with cell above A1 (24.11,2017) turns cell A2 interior into red
- Next date is compared with cell above (offset (-1,0))
Example
Cell A3 (26.11.2017) compared with cell above A2 (26.11.2017) turns cell A3 interior same as A2 interior,

Comment: - Next date/cell
Cell A4 (30.11.2017) compared to cell above A3 (26.11.2017) turns cell A4 interior into blue
- Cell A5 (30.11.2017) compared to cell above A4 (30.11.2017) turns cell A% interior same as A4 interior,
- ....
- There might be blank cells in date column, formatting of blanked cells doesnt matter (can be collored as red, blue, or no color)
Dates range is very big (any date between 2007 – now (future)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data start in cell A1. I think this can probably be simplified a bit.

However,

```
Public Sub ColourCells()

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Dim lastRow As Long

   lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Dim loopRange As Range

   Set loopRange = wsSource.Range("A1:A" & lastRow) ' adjust here if starts elsewhere

   Dim currValue As Variant
   Dim cellColor As String

   cellColor = vbBlue

   Dim currCell As Range

   For Each currCell In loopRange.Rows

       If Not IsEmpty(currCell) Then

           If currCell.Row = 1 Then 
                currCell.Font.Color = cellColor
                currValue = currCell.Value2

           ElseIf currCell = currValue Then
                currCell.Font.Color = cellColor

           Else
                If cellColor = vbBlue Then
                    cellColor = vbRed
                Else  
                    cellColor = vbBlue
                End If

                currCell.Font.Color = cellColor
                currValue = currCell.Value2

          End If

       End If

   Next currCell

End sub
```

Comment: QHarr When I see you, I will buy You a beer. You program works great. It is simple, and most of all do the job. Once more, many thanks. Regards, Marko

Comment: Pleased to have helped.